# Domain Driven Design Models: Customer Service Case, more denormalized, flat-wide?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, domain-driven-design

In Domain Business models in software, are domain models generally more denormalized? I had  question about this particular example say,

These is Customer Service Case in Database.

In the Domain Model,

Should I place all the fields into 1 class, Combine CustomerService, CustomerServiceStatus, Type, etc into 1 Domain Class (one flat wide table), or should I keep the original Data model structure normalized ?
I believe CustomerService Case Is Aggregate Root pointing to the Lookup tables,  Type, and Status etc?

**Scaffold Models from Database:**

**CustomerService Case**

```
public class CustomerServiceCase
{
    public int CustomerServiceCaseId { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerServiceCaseStatusId { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerServiceCaseTypeId { get; set; }
    public int? LastModifiedByUserId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerServiceCaseNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CustomerServiceCaseReceiveDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CustomerServiceCaseCreateDate { get; set; }

    public virtual CustomerServiceCaseStatus CustomerServiceCaseStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerServiceCaseType CustomerServiceCaseType { get; set; }

}
```

**Customer Case Service Status:**

```
public class CustomerServiceCaseStatus
{
    public int CustomerServiceCaseStatusId { get; set; }
    public int? LastModifiedByUserId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerServiceCaseStatusCode { get; set; }
    public string CustomerServiceCaseStatusDescription { get; set; }
    public bool? Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EffectiveStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EffectiveEndDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CustomerServiceCase> CustomerServiceCase { get; set; }
}
```

**Customer Service Case Type:**

```
public class CustomerServiceCaseType
{
    public int CustomerServiceCaseTypeId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerServiceCaseTypeCode { get; set; }
    public string CustomerServiceCaseTypeDescription { get; set; }
    public int? LastModifiedByUserId { get; set; }
    public bool? Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EffectiveStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EffectiveEndDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CustomerServiceCase> CustomerServiceCase { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your use case entirely (like the need for separately storing `CustomerServiceCaseType` - I imagine the case types to be finite and well-defined). You may be talking about a master table for storing `CustomerServiceCaseType` which you are referring to in your `CustomerServiceCase` class.

Irrespective of that, let me answer generically from a Domain-Driven Design point of view.

**DDD itself does not care about how the data is stored in the underlying persistence store.** Your domain model should be database-agnostic and not care about what kind of infrastructure is being used.

All persistence related aspects should be handled by repositories. They are responsible for loading and persisting aggregates, and they are free to handle this in any way they see fit. These repositories are typically used by Application Services to load and persist data.

If you use a document store like MongoDB, your aggregate would probably be stored as one big document, including its own fields as well as those of the entities and value object it encloses. So the repository just needs to make one query to the database.

If you use an RDBMS, you would probably end up having a denormalized structure. Then your repository will either do multiple calls or use joins, to load the data. But it does so whenever the aggregate is loaded. Linkages should not be evaluated lazily when the aggregate is loaded,  because the Aggregate should satisfy all invariants across its enclosed domain objects.

Here is a crude pseudocode example that shows the disconnect between the domain objects, and the data store.

```
##############
Domain Classes
##############

class Order
{
    String order_number;
    List<OrderLine> order_lines;
    Timestamp ordered_on;
    String status;

    public Order build(params)
    {
        ...
    }
}

class OrderLine
{
    Integer product_id;
    Float price;
    Float quantity;
    Float tax;
    Float total;
    Integer sequence;
    String shipped_status;

    public OrderLine build(params)
    {
        ...
    }
}

###################
Application Service
###################

class OrderService
{
    Boolean place_order(params)
    {
        IRepository OrderRepository;  // Repository object is injected here

        new_order = Order.build(params);

        OrderRepository.create_new_order(new_order);
    }
}

##############
Infrastructure
##############

class OrderRepository extends IRepository
{
    public create_new_order(order)
    {
        // This is for illustration purposes only. You would probably use ORM tool to accomplish this.
        order_sql = "INSERT INTO order VALUES".format(order.order_number, order.ordered_on, ...)

        List<String> order_line_sqls;
        for each order_line in order.order_lines
        {
            order_line_sqls.append("INSERT into order_line VALUES(?, ?, ...)".format(order_line.product_id, order_line.price, ...))
        }

        // You would use a Unit of Work here
        result = db.exec(order_sql)
        if result = true:
            for each order_line_sql in order_line_sqls
            {
                result = db.exec(order_line_sql)
                if result != true:
                    raise Error("Transaction Failed")  // and rollback
            }
    }
}
```

The following is an example of the opposite case, where there is one domain element, but is stored in two separate tables (maybe for reasons like performance, reporting, data export, etc. though I have never done it personally in my past projects):

```
class User
{
    String email;
    String username;
    String password;
    String address1;
    String address2;
    String address3;
    String city;
    String province;
    String zipcode;

    public User build(params)
    {
        ...
    }
}

class UserRepository extends IRepository
{
    public static persist_user(user)
    {
        // This is for illustration purposes only. You would probably use ORM tool to accomplish this.
        user_sql = "INSERT INTO user VALUES(?, ?, ?, ...)".format(user.email, user.username, user.password)
        address_sql = "INSERT INTO user_address VALUES(?, ?, ?, ...)".format(user.address1, user.city, ...)

        // You would use a Unit of Work here
        result = db.exec(user_sql)
        if result = true
        {
            result = db.exec(address_sql)
            if result != true
            {
                raise Error("Transaction Failed")  // and rollback
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks to address first point, the class examples above were scaffold models EF from database, can you give example in answer then how domain class should look like? you said denormalized? was I on the right path? I read an article today how OrderHeader and Orderdetail tables should be as one in domain model, but in database they are separate ,also read lookup tables should reside in Enums?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include an example. I am assuming your domain still contains `Order` and `OrderDetail` as two independent elements. `Order` would be the aggregate, and `OrderDetail` would be an entity enclosed within `Order` aggregate.

Comment: thanks, that's interesting, that's how Entity Framework would scaffold database anyway, order and orderline would be two tables, and orderline would then be a collection in order when scaffold, is that not correct? so in these two cases the data and domain model are similar

Comment: That's correct. Now, if for some reason you would want to shift to a Document DB like Mongo, you would need only to change your repository. Your repository would persist the `Order` aggregate as-is, with `OrderLine` collection within it. The domain layer, with all its invariants and business logic, would remain unchanged.

Comment: yeah, thanks interesting, trying to find a case where Domain and data model are different

Comment: I think I understand now what you are looking for. An example I could give is a `Person` and his `Address`. Added another example with pseudocode. Does that help? You would do something like only when you are addressing performance issues, or you are going to use the table differently, like reporting. I have not used this ever in my past DDD projects, though; never had the occasion.

Comment: just trying to see an example where a Data model scaffold looks different from a Domain model, the order orderline example above was accidentally the same model for data and domain, thanks